# Explode simple XML file in pyspark (Not using databricks)

Tags: python, xml, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-xml

I have a XML file which is given below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <item id="0001" type="donut">
        <name>Cake</name>
        <ppu>0.55</ppu>
        <batters>
            <batter id="1001">Regular</batter>
            <batter id="1002">Chocolate</batter>
            <batter id="1003">Blueberry</batter>
        </batters>
        <topping id="5001">None</topping>
        <topping id="5002">Glazed</topping>
        <topping id="5005">Sugar</topping>
        <topping id="5006">Sprinkles</topping>
        <topping id="5003">Chocolate</topping>
        <topping id="5004">Maple</topping>
    </item>
</items>
```

How can i explode batter and topping and flatten it into table format ?

Comment: The question is not clear? Please explain. What is the expected output?

Comment: why don't you use this [package](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) ? It is provided by databricks but it is not only available on databricks.  you can import it in your env

Comment: I want to know how can i use explode funtion in this xml file.